# Input field not updated in Reactive Forms Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive forms in an Angular application.
I have 2 fields, one is a select (named client) and the other one an input (named clientCode) which has to be updated the user selects a new client.

```
<select formControlName="client">
            <option value="">Client</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of data.clients" [value]="item.value">{{ item.value }}</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" formControlName="clientCode" placeholder="Client Code" value="{{ clientCode$ | async }}">
```

I'm using valueChanges over client, so that when the user selects a client I get the code associated to that client and it returns it as an Observable (clientCode$) which then updates the input value.

```
this.clientCode$ = this.summary
      .get('client')
      .valueChanges.map(val => this.clientsMap.get(val));
```

This is working in my screen, as the clientCode is displayed, but the form itself is not updated. Only when I click in the input field and type something is updated.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Moving `{{ clientCode$ }}` from `value=` to inside inside input tags might help: `<input ... >{{ clientCode$ }}</input>`. Also, closing your input field may fix it: `<input ... / >` or `<input ...></input>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to update control model successfully you can use `ngModel` property instead of `value`.

It might look like:

```
[ngModel]="clientCode$ | async"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xpefxPKxxsXKXoDkLIuf?p=preview)**

Comment: @r0b3rt0 That's good that you read the documentation but please don't write such comments if you don't know how it works. In my plunker example i even didn't import FormsModule. ngModel is just `@Input` for reactive FormControlName